# Windows RT unable to add/reuse Microsoft user account

Tags: microsoft-account, windows-rt

Recently, I need to add a user account to Windows RT (Surface 2). I got an error of

`Sorry, we couldn't connect to Microsoft services right now. If this problem persists, search for "network problems" on the Start screen`.

On the other hand, it lets me create a new Microsoft account (outlook.com / hotmail.com) and then I can sign in using that account.

I try to get around it by creating a local account and try converting the local account to Microsoft account but I am getting the same "Sorry, we couldn't connect to Microsoft services right now" error.

At this point, I am stuck. I have not found any news about Microsoft sign-in service being offline. Any ideas how I can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I found a thread that reports the very same issue.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfwinrt-surfupdate/cant-login-to-microsoft-accountreset-surface-rt/563b7108-1267-40be-84b8-2fe62b2e75be

The first incident was reported on 9/18/2017 and as of now (10/10/2017) it is still unresolved. It appears to due to Microsoft shutting down an authentication server used by Windows RT.

With a luck of the draw, I managed to convert my local account into a Microsoft account. I tried some many things so I can't tell which one does the trick. I signed in to Windows Store and after a couple of attempts, I was able to sign-in. And then, I installed updates. Subsequently, I went to Accounts and "connect to Microsoft account". It asked me for password and it worked!

However, I still have the problem of not able to add another Microsoft account. I am holding off from making any changes to the OS until I see reports in the above thread that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
At first all was working, and then it did not.
So it must be a recent update I thought.
And that it was.
I removed KB3072019 and that solved my problem.